# Flutter WSL2 and debug with chrome windows error "can't reand and write on /tmp/flutter.tools.YRLOKA/flutter_tools_device.XXXXX"

Tags: flutter-web, wsl-2

i'm using flutter on Debian/WSL2 on windows 11 (last updated on 22/01/2022) with vscode.

I want to debug a Flutter Web app from  WSL2 and the Debug on chrome Windows (i've saw we can launch chrome windows version from Linux via WSL2).

What i did :

I've configured some options to use chrome.exe (windows version) via user env variables on widows:

```
SET CHROME_EXECUTABLE=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
SET WSLENV=CHROME_EXECUTABLE/p
```

on wsl, i can verify the conf is ok :

```
echo $CHROME_EXECUTABLE
/mnt/c/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

Flutter doctor (i'm using fvm) seems OK :

```
fvm flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I've noticed that when i run flutter doctor, chrome.exe is launched... i don't understand why ...?

But the main problem is when i run my flutter web in debug mode frome vscode, chrome.exe is launched immediately without url.

Then when vscode has finished and is waiting chrome to debug, chrome.exe is opened 4 times on the url like "http://localhost:44707/" but i see nothing in the browser, even if i click "dart debug extension".
And I have multiple error "can't reand and write on /tmp/flutter.tools.YRLOKA/flutter_tools_device.XXXXX""

How can i debug on chrome.exe from WSL2 ?

thanks,

EDIT : i've tested chrome installation on my WSL2, but the performances are bad...chrome has no gui acceleration with default installation. And do installation of chrome twice is not a good idea. I don't want to install/work on Flutter on windows platform because I build all my apps on linux ans Macos.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. The gist of it is **Windows** does cannot access the WSL2 temp directory "/tmp/flutter.tools...". [Have a look at the code responsible for such an error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/68f02dd2e83a0c74c331d7004ec1fb5db49617f7/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart#L188-L201).

Basically, chrome is being launched on Windows with a WSL path directory, which cannot be read. I think the solution is to probably have flutter both on Windows and WSL2, unless flutter provides a configuration parameter for the chrome temp folder.

EDIT: I have upgraded to Windows 11 and installed chrome in WSL2. Now it works.